# how to install a module with npm in angular 1

Tags: angularjs, npm, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to install bootstrap using npm.  I ran:

```
npm install angular-ui-bootstrap
```

And that succesfully installed the module in the `node_modules` folder.  The problem is I can't seem to reference the files from index.html.  I put in the following line:

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

But it returns a 404.  I have 3 questions:

1. Am I referencing the right file
2. How do I include the file in index.html
3. If I include the file in the html, will that be enough to erase another error I'm getting:

   ```
   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available!
   ```

Here is the file structure:

```
Project
    -app
        -index.html
    -node_modules
        -angular-ui-bootstrap
            -dist
                -ui-bootstrap.js
```

Comment: Can you provide your filestructure around `node_modules/`?

Comment: Yes, I just added it.

Comment: Try adding `../` to the beginning of your reference. You need to move up out of the `app/` directory.

Comment: use `<script src="../node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>`

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel thanks, that's what i thought but it doesn't work.  I get the exact same error

Comment: @Pradeepb I'm using npm, not bower.

Comment: Yep. just updated.

Comment: @Pradeepb Thanks, I tried that but i get the same error.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `ui-bootstrap.js` is in that directory?

Comment: Also, how are you hosting this application? Is your document root pointed at `app/`?

Comment: The file is definitely in the directory.  I'm running the server in the "project" folder

Comment: can you show what order you are loading your scripts in the index.html file?

Comment: Are you using Express or Django (or some other framework with a path router), which might be intercepting the request for the file? Do you have static file repositories set up?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `/` from `<script src="/node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>`
Like this:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
```